# compare the average purchase_amount between two time ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

The question is as follows:

How high was the average purchase amount in the morning (05-11) compared to (17-23) in the evening?

I don't know how to compare them.

I tried this but I only get one big amount.

```
select avg(purchase_amount)
from case_data_order
where cast (create_timestamp as time ) between '05:00:00' and '11:00:00'
or cast(create_timestamp as time) between '17:00:00' and '23:00:00';
```

I use Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 1):

try going with `FILTER` predicate, like this:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS unfiltered,
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE i < 5) AS filtered
FROM generate_series(1,10) AS s(i);
 unfiltered | filtered
------------+----------
         10 |        4
(1 row)
```

so in your case it would be something like

```
select 
  avg(purchase_amount) FILTER (where cast (create_timestamp as time ) between '05:00:00' and '11:00:00') as morning
  , avg(purchase_amount) FILTER (where cast (create_timestamp as time ) between '17:00:00' and '23:00:00') as evening
from case_data_order
```

Answer (score 0):

smth like could help:

```
  SELECT
    AVG(purchase_amount),
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '11:00:00'
        THEN 'day'
        WHEN CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '23:00:00'
        THEN 'night'
    END gr
FROM case_data_order
WHERE CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '11:00:00'
      OR CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '23:00:00'
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '11:00:00'
        THEN 'day'
        WHEN CAST(create_timestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '23:00:00'
        THEN 'night'
    END gr;
```

Answer (score 0):

How to get the averages:

```
select d,
       avg(case when t between '05:00:00' and '11:00:00' then purchase_amount end) as am,
       avg(case when t between '17:00:00' and '23:00:00' then purchase_amount end) as pm
from
(
    select purchase_amount,
           cast(create_timestamp as time) as t,
           cast(create_timestamp as date) as d
    from case_data_order
) dt
group by d
```